# Best way to recreate snapshots in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, snapshot

I want to update database snapshot every hour, keeping its name unchanged. Only way I found how to do this - drop/create pattern. But there is 3 minutes downtime between DROP and CREATE events.
Is there a way to update snapshot faster?

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer turned out to be junk because you can't re-name database snapshots. What you can do, however, is create a shell database whose only job is to contain synonyms to objects in your database snapshot. It'd work something like this:

1. Create new database snapshot
2. Create synonyms to objects in new snapshot, dropping old synonyms where necessary
3. Once all synonyms have been repointed, drop old snapshot.

Comment: That is often the trade off. :)